# mySQL query: How to insert with UNION?

Tags: select, mysql, union

I am kind of new to mySQL:s union functions, at least when doing inserts with them. I have gotten the following to work based upon a example found on the net:

```
INSERT INTO tableOne(a, b)
SELECT a, $var FROM tableOne
WHERE b = $var2
UNION ALL SELECT $var,$var
```

Ok, nothing strange about that. But what happens when I want to insert a third value into the database that has nothing to do with the logic of the Select being done?

Like : `INSERT INTO tableOne(a, b, c )`

How could that be done?

Comment: Found a good answer here, Hope it helps someone. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20667/mysql-insert-into-select-union

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can "select" literal values too:

```
mysql> select 'hello', 1;
+-------+---+
| hello | 1 |
+-------+---+
| hello | 1 |
+-------+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hence, you can also use that in `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` and `UNION`s.

```
INSERT INTO someTable (a, b, c) VALUES
SELECT id, name, 5
FROM someOtherTable
UNION
SELECT id, alias, 8
FROM anotherTable
```

Comment: At least for sqlite3, it seems that there should be no `VALUES` in this case. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html .