# Insert into with union

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem. There are three tables: T1, T2, T_target. T1 and T2 table have many different columns but I need only the ID column from both. The T_target table has an ID column of course and another: project_No.

There are some IDs which appears in T1 and T2 too, but I don't want to create duplicates between them, if an ID appears in both table it have to be inserted into the T_target only once but if it is already in the T_target it's allowed to act twice. The other of the criteria is every newly inserted ID must be value 21 in 'project_No' column. So, e.g.:

**T1:**

```
ID
2548
2566
2569
2843
2888
...
```

**T2:**

```
ID
2557
2566
2569
2700
2913
2994
3018
5426
...
```

**T_target:**

```
ID     project_No
2976   1
3331   7
4049   7
5426   8
5915   3
6253   10
...
```

And the result I want to see:

**T_target:**

```
ID     project_No
2548   21
2557   21
2566   21
2569   21
2700   21
2843   21
2888   21
2913   21
2976   1
2994   21
2018   21
3331   7
4049   7
5426   8
5426   21
5915   3
6253   10
...
```

So, I tried it with this code (it is important to be here "NOT NULL" criteria because both of T_target columns are primary key):

```
insert into T_target (ID, project_No)
  select (select ID
  from T1 where ID is not NULL
 union
  select ID
  from T2 where ID is not NULL), 21

select * from T_target
```

The error message:
**"Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated."**

Then I tried with VALUES statement instead of the first SELECT and parentheses but the error is the same.

There is a similar problem:
[mySQL query: How to insert with UNION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958235/mysql-query-how-to-insert-with-union)
but this solution doesn't work for me because it indicates syntax error between VALUE and SELECT.

Please, give me a hand.
Thank you!

Comment: I haven't read most of your question, but I think the correct syntax for your existing query is: `insert into T_target (ID, project_No) select ID, 21 from T1 where ID is not NULL union select ID, 21 from T2 where ID is not NULL`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This should do what you need

```
INSERT INTO T_target
            (ID,
             project_No)
SELECT ID,
       21
FROM   T1
WHERE  ID IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT ID,
       21
FROM   T2
WHERE  ID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I usually would write an if statement, but when using this strategy it saves me from having to write the insert portion multiple times, love this solution thanks, will be doing it this way from now on when possible. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to amend that a little to avoid duplication of the ID's in the select statement.

```
INSERT INTO T_target
            (ID,
             project_No)

SELECT ID, 21 
FROM (
SELECT ID
FROM   T1
WHERE  ID IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT ID
FROM   T2
WHERE  ID IS NOT NULL 
) A
```