# Is it possible to store data in database using UNION and EXCEPT commands?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

Is it possible to store data in database using UNION and EXCEPT commands in query or we have to use `INSERT`?

If it is possible please tell me how? if not, is it possible to use `EXCEPT` and `UNION` with `INSERT` commands?

> I've seen the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160298/insert-into-with-union) as well.

Comment: In that link there is usage of INSERT + UNION.

Comment: @NiVeR yeah of course! but first of all I want to ensure that there isn't any possible way and then try to find out how can I use EXCEPT and UNION together.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve]. PS SQL question should always give the product because they differ. PS Your comment is not clear. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` and `EXCEPT` are *set* operations that are used with the `SELECT` statement.  The statements that modify data are:

- `UPDATE`
- `INSERT`
- `DELETE`
- `MERGE` (in some databases)

All of these can accept a `SELECT` subquery somewhere in the statement.  `UNION` and `EXCEPT` could be used with *that* `SELECT` as part of a larger operation.

Answer (score 0):

How can a new record be unioned or excepted without inserting/storing it into the database likewise How can you store it either with the same. However Insert can be used interchangebly with union and except to store either related columns data or with filtering with except statements. It works when you manually have to enter the data but if you want to extract and insert then you require use of select as well.