# Bulk insert using multiple select statement

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using php & mysql. I have a table called "summary" and dont want to use insert statement inside for-each loop. So What I have written the following code.

All the values concatenated in the userData Array inside loop and appended the userData Array in the Insert Query into a variable called $sql.

```
<?php
foreach ($activities as $activity) {
    $userData[] = "(SELECT A.AcctDb,'" . $default->DeftReportPeriod . "', '" . $default->DeftReportBase . "', '" . $default->DeftPeriodBasis . "', '" . $default->DeftBasisAdj . "', '" . $AcctNo . "','" . $AcctTaxId . "', '" . $RevLoc . "', '" . $YTDStart . "', '" . $CurrFreq . "', '" . $Curr . "', '" . $Ytd . "', '" . $Lastcurr . "', '" . $LastYTD . "', '" . $Last12 . "', '" . $Prior12 . "', '" . $Last12diff . "', A.AcctDateOpen, A.AcctDateClosed, A.GroupCode, A.AcctHomeLoc, A.AcctBusName, A.ClassCode, '" . $Currdiff . "', '" . $Ytddiff . "', '" . $Mon['0'] . "', '" . $Mon['1'] . "', '" . $Mon['2'] . "', '" . $Mon['3'] . "', '" . $Mon['4'] . "', '" . $Mon['5'] . "', '" . $Mon['6'] . "', '" . $Mon['7'] . "', '" . $Mon['8'] . "', '" . $Mon['9'] . "', '" . $Mon['10'] . "', '" . $Mon['11'] . "','" . $Amt['0'] . "', '" . $Amt['1'] . "', '" . $Amt['2'] . "','" . $Amt['3'] . "', '" . $Amt['4'] . "', '" . $Amt['5'] . "', '" . $Amt['6'] . "', '" . $Amt['7'] . "', '" . $Amt['8'] . "', '" . $Amt['9'] . "', '" . $Amt['10'] . "', '" . $Amt['11'] . "' FROM accounts A WHERE A.AcctDb = '" . $AcctDb . "' and A.AcctTaxId='" . $AcctTaxId . "')";
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO summary (AcctDb, SumReportPer, SumReportBase, SumPeriodBasis, SumBasisAdj, AcctNo,AcctTaxId, SumRevLoc, SumYtdStart, SumCurrFreq, SumCurrAmt, SumYtdAmt, SumLastCurr, SumLastYtd, SumLast12, SumPrior12, SumLast12Diff, SumDateOpen, SumDateClosed, SumGroupCode, SumHomeLoc, SumBusName, SumClassCode, SumCurrDiff, SumYtdDiff, SumMon01, SumMon02, SumMon03, SumMon04, SumMon05, SumMon06, SumMon07, SumMon08, SumMon09, SumMon10, SumMon11, SumMon12, SumAmt01, SumAmt02, SumAmt03, SumAmt04, SumAmt05, SumAmt06, SumAmt07, SumAmt08, SumAmt09, SumAmt10, SumAmt11, SumAmt12) SELECT ' . implode(',', $userData);

$this->db->query($sql);
?>
```

What's my issue is, For the single records(printed the query), the query is getting executed.

### For Single Record - Query Executed Successfully

```
INSERT INTO summary (AcctDb, SumReportPer, SumReportBase, SumPeriodBasis, SumBasisAdj, AcctNo,AcctTaxId, SumRevLoc, SumYtdStart, SumCurrFreq, SumCurrAmt, SumYtdAmt, SumLastCurr, SumLastYtd, SumLast12, SumPrior12, SumLast12Diff, SumDateOpen, SumDateClosed, SumGroupCode, SumHomeLoc, SumBusName, SumClassCode, SumCurrDiff, SumYtdDiff, SumMon01, SumMon02, SumMon03, SumMon04, SumMon05, SumMon06, SumMon07, SumMon08, SumMon09, SumMon10, SumMon11, SumMon12, SumAmt01, SumAmt02, SumAmt03, SumAmt04, SumAmt05, SumAmt06, SumAmt07, SumAmt08, SumAmt09, SumAmt10, SumAmt11, SumAmt12)(SELECT A.AcctDb,'201310', 'R', 'C', '2', '014000956','014000956', '2200', '201211', 'M', '0', '35215.12', '10968.01', '51717.3', '35215.12', '51717.3', '-16502.18', A.AcctDateOpen, A.AcctDateClosed, A.GroupCode, A.AcctHomeLoc, A.AcctBusName, A.ClassCode, '-10968.01', '-16502.18', '', '3118.72', '2037.24', '2819.42', '1345.73', '4817.26', '8046.78', '4678.11', '59.44', '106.54', '4077.1', '4108.78','', '1', '1','1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' FROM accounts A WHERE A.AcctDb = 'A' and A.AcctTaxId='014000956')
```

### For Multiple Record - Throws an error

```
INSERT INTO summary (AcctDb, SumReportPer, SumReportBase, SumPeriodBasis, SumBasisAdj, AcctNo,AcctTaxId, SumRevLoc, SumYtdStart, SumCurrFreq, SumCurrAmt, SumYtdAmt, SumLastCurr, SumLastYtd, SumLast12, SumPrior12, SumLast12Diff, SumDateOpen, SumDateClosed, SumGroupCode, SumHomeLoc, SumBusName, SumClassCode, SumCurrDiff, SumYtdDiff, SumMon01, SumMon02, SumMon03, SumMon04, SumMon05, SumMon06, SumMon07, SumMon08, SumMon09, SumMon10, SumMon11, SumMon12, SumAmt01, SumAmt02, SumAmt03, SumAmt04, SumAmt05, SumAmt06, SumAmt07, SumAmt08, SumAmt09, SumAmt10, SumAmt11, SumAmt12)(SELECT A.AcctDb,'201310', 'R', 'C', '2', '014000956','014000956', '2200', '201211', 'M', '0', '35215.12', '10968.01', '51717.3', '35215.12', '51717.3', '-16502.18', A.AcctDateOpen, A.AcctDateClosed, A.GroupCode, A.AcctHomeLoc, A.AcctBusName, A.ClassCode, '-10968.01', '-16502.18', '', '3118.72', '2037.24', '2819.42', '1345.73', '4817.26', '8046.78', '4678.11', '59.44', '106.54', '4077.1', '4108.78','', '1', '1','1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' FROM accounts A WHERE A.AcctDb = 'A' and A.AcctTaxId='014000956'),(SELECT A.AcctDb,'201310', 'R', 'C', '2', '014000956','014000956', '2201', '201211', 'M', '0', '13.86', '0', '15.22', '13.86', '15.22', '-1.36', A.AcctDateOpen, A.AcctDateClosed, A.GroupCode, A.AcctHomeLoc, A.AcctBusName, A.ClassCode, '0', '-1.36', '', '', '', '8.89', '', '4.97', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '','1', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '' FROM accounts A WHERE A.AcctDb = 'A' and A.AcctTaxId='014000956')
```

The error is
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT A.AcctDb,'201310', 'R', 'C', '2', '014000956','014000956', '2201', '2012' at line 1****

May I know, What I am doing wrong here, any input from the stackoverflow community might help us to resolve this issue.

I have added the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aa2467

Comment: Which database framework are you using here? The way you're composing queries is extremely worrying since it doesn't look like you're [properly escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) those values.

Comment: There is no difference whatsoever in the two input statements you have shown. And while you fix that, please insert appropriate line breaks as well.

Comment: using codeigniter framework, in that mysql database(default) one

Comment: Then you'll want to be super extra sure you've read the part on [escaping in the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html).

Comment: modified the multiple record query

Comment: Do you have a field called `'-10968.01'` because thats where you are trying to insert data

Comment: it is not a field, I am inserting the values using multiple select statement query in loop

Comment: Use [`UNION` instead of `(SELECT),(SELECT)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958235/mysql-query-how-to-insert-with-union)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below post answers my solution

[mySQL query: How to insert with UNION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958235/mysql-query-how-to-insert-with-union)

I supposed to use UNION instead of (SELECT),(SELECT) @Wrikken

So, the correct query will be like below

```
    INSERT INTO summary (AcctDb, SumReportPer, SumReportBase, SumPeriodBasis, SumBasisAdj, AcctNo,AcctTaxId, SumRevLoc, SumYtdStart, SumCurrFreq, SumCurrAmt, SumYtdAmt, SumLastCurr, SumLastYtd, SumLast12, SumPrior12, SumLast12Diff, SumDateOpen, SumDateClosed, SumGroupCode, SumHomeLoc, SumBusName, SumClassCode, SumCurrDiff, SumYtdDiff, SumMon01, SumMon02, SumMon03, SumMon04, SumMon05, SumMon06, SumMon07, SumMon08, SumMon09, SumMon10, SumMon11, SumMon12, SumAmt01, SumAmt02, SumAmt03, SumAmt04, SumAmt05, SumAmt06, SumAmt07, SumAmt08, SumAmt09, SumAmt10, SumAmt11, SumAmt12) 
    SELECT A.AcctDb,'201310', 'R', 'D', '2', '014000956','014000956', '2200', '201211', 'M', '0', '35215.12', '10968.01', '51717.3', '35215.12', '51717.3', '-16502.18', A.AcctDateOpen, A.AcctDateClosed, A.GroupCode, A.AcctHomeLoc, A.AcctBusName, A.ClassCode, '-10968.01', '-16502.18', '', '3118.72', '2037.24', '2819.42', '1345.73', '4817.26', '8046.78', '4678.11', '59.44', '106.54', '4077.1', '4108.78','', '1', '1','1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1' FROM accounts A WHERE A.AcctDb = 'A' and A.AcctTaxId='014000956' 
    UNION 
    SELECT A.AcctDb,'201310', 'R', 'E', '2', '014000957','014000957', '2201', '201211', 'M', '0', '13.86', '0', '15.22', '13.86', '15.22', '-1.36', A.AcctDateOpen, A.AcctDateClosed, A.GroupCode, A.AcctHomeLoc, A.AcctBusName, A.ClassCode, '0', '-1.36', '', '', '', '8.89', '', '4.97', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '','1', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '' FROM accounts A WHERE A.AcctDb = 'A' and A.AcctTaxId='014000956'
```