# Combine MySQL databases

Tags: mysql

I have daily dumps of a certain database. What I want to do is to merge a specific table records from different dumps of the database into one table. For example if I have table X for day 1 and table X for day 2, these two tables are basically the same thing with overlapping records. I want to get only one table X with the data of two of them combined. The table has a primary key called 'id'.

Table X day 1

```
id   field1   field2
1    0        0
2    1        2
```

Table X day 2

```
id   field1   field2
1    0        0
3    1        3
```

What I need:

Table X

```
id   field1   field2
1    0        0
2    1        2
3    1        3
```

What is the best way to do it? Is it possible to do it in MySQL itself or I need a code to take care of it?

PLEASE NOTE: This table x exists in different databases. Basically I import those daily dumps in MySQL and it gives a unique database for each day.

Thanks

Comment: I can't understand exactly what you want. Do you mean that you have dumps that you would like to merge on a new mysql schema? and should the table get an new name automatically?

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad Basically I have 10 dumps from a single database over a period of 10 days. There is a table in this database which changes over time. All I want to do is to get records of this table from those 10 days and merge them into one table in a new database maybe. Thanks

Comment: Is your dump of this table only or is it of the whole database? Can you call a script before you load your dump?

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad The dums are from the whole database. I have .frm MYI and MYD files which I copy in to the mysql directory to load them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to find the query which gives you the result that you want, the next step is you can create a view like `create view tablex as` for create a table with `create table tablex as select ....`.
For you case you have to combine your result using the `union` clause:

```
 Select id, field1, field2 from table1
 union
 Select id, field2, field2 from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Tablex (id, field1, field2) VALUES
SELECT id, field1, field2
FROM someOtherTable
UNION
SELECT id, field1, field2
FROM anotherTable
```

Check here [mySQL query: How to insert with UNION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958235/mysql-query-how-to-insert-with-union)